# Adding to a dictionary and printing from it python

Tags: python

I'm creating a poll system, for example

```
Name:vote Greg:chocolate
Name:vote Teena:macaroons
Name:vote Georgina:apple pie
Name:vote Will:chocolate
Name:vote Sophia:gelato
Name:vote Sam:ice cream
Name:vote James:chocolate
Name:vote Kirsten:gelato
Name:vote
apple pie 1 vote(s): Georgina
gelato 2 vote(s): Sophia Kirsten
chocolate 3 vote(s): Greg Will James
macaroons 1 vote(s): Teena
ice cream 1 vote(s): Sam
```

My current code is completely broken, As I'm not that strong with dictionary.

```
Current Code:
votes = {}

userinput = input("Name:vote ")
for word in userinput.strip().split():
  name = ""
  food = ""
  key = (name, food)
  votes[key]
print(votes)
```

Comment: `votes[key] += 1` ?

Comment: Also it looks like you want to split using `:` as a separator but your `.split()` call does not specify that.

Comment: To get the name/vote combo split on `:` e.g. `val.split(':')`. Presently you are splitting on the default i.e. spaces. The other thing you need to do is produce a dict which is keyed on the vote string and holds a list of names. For this it might be simplest to use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Use `votes[vote].append(name)`. The final thing you need to do to print out is to use `votes.items()` to retrieve tuples of keys and value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want you input to be strictly 'user:input' and you want to repeat this indefinitely depending how many votes you need to input, you will need a loop. Each time the user adds an entry you add it to a list. You can set a clause variable based on the input, for example, if the user types 'end' it breaks the loop.

```
userinputs = []
end = False

while end == False:
    entry = input("Enter Name:Vote")
    if entry == 'end':
        end = True
    else:
        userinputs.append(entry)
```

Once you have that you can populate a dictionary with another loop, similar to how you did it. As the input convention is strictly 'name:vote' you can split with the ':' character and add the respective values to the dictionary:

```
for entry in userinputs:
  name = entry.split(':')[0]
  food = entry.split(':')[1]
  votes[name] = food

print(votes)
```

My advice would be to think about ways you can design this in such a way that the input convention is not strictly 'name:vote', and maybe how you could make this program more robust to errors (of which there are many).